# how to set multi hasMany connection between model?

Tags: php, doctrine

im using doctrine-project

and i have 3 tables

```
table 1: post
--------------
postid , title , date , some more fields....


table 2: tags
---------------
tagid , title


table3: post_tags 
--------------------
post_tags_id , tagid , postid
```

table 3 is link between tags and posts which mean
each post get tags through post_tags

now in base Post model i have :

```
     $this->hasMany('PostTags as TagLink', array(
            'refClass' => 'PostTags',
            'local' => 'postid',
            'foreign' => 'postid'
        )

    );
```

which links the model to PostsTags model

and in PostsTags model i have assc "belongs to" to Post model and Tag model

now im runing the query :

```
$q = Doctrine::getTable('posts')->findAll();
```

now if i want to get tags i do `$q->PostsTags->Tags`

but i dont really care about PostsTags becouse its only link

so i want to do just

`$q->Tags`

and getting taglist for the post

how can i do that ?

Comment: Your question is easier to read if you use proper punctuation and capital letters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Doctrine Using Many-to-many](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/pl/working-with-models:many-to-many-relations)

[Doctrine Defining Many-to-many](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/pl/defining-models#relationships:join-table-associations:many-to-many)

Comment: thank you very much , i didnt know what was the name of this kind of relation :)